# Chromium Kiosk go fullscreen on raspberry pi3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspberry-pi3

I have problem with starting chromium on raspberry pi3, 
python code  starts  at boot in /etc/profile

```
cd /home/pi/Documents/raspberry/
DISPLAY=:0 python3 script.py
```

loader.html loads normaly, then index.html goes out of kiosk mode and it is displayed full screen but there is taskbar at the top, even if i hide task bard the code goes only to full screen opened as window (without tabs).

```
        def openstart(name="loader"):
            if name=="index":
                subprocess.Popen(['chromium-browser','--allow-file-access-from-files', '--kiosk', 'file:///home/pi/Documents/raspberry/'+name+'.html']) 
            else:
                subprocess.Popen(['chromium-browser','--allow-file-access-from-files', '--kiosk', 'file

    :///home/pi/Documents/raspberry/'+name+'.html'])    
        return True

openstart()
openstart("index")
```

Comment: There's a couple of newlines there that might cause the issue. Can you try removing them from "file

    :///home/pi/Documents/raspberry/'+name+'.html'])" to "file:///home/pi/Documents/raspberry/'+name+'.html'])"

Comment: @BoboDarph there is no new line :/

Comment: The code you pasted says otherwise